# Auto-completing words on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, productivity

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that allows the user to auto-complete words in any program.

For example, if the user types `soft`, the program could suggest `software` or `soften` in a dropbown menu, similarly to the auto-completion feature present in most IDEs:

[image]

Ideally:

- the program should allow the user to view the auto-completion options by using a keyboard shortcut.
- the options given by the program are listed by likelihood (e.g., using some language model)
- the program could be disabled in some programs.

Any price or license is fine.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbWFBy
- https://redd.it/6a6bas

Comment: Frank, since you also posted elsewhere, if you get an answer elsewhere, could you please post it here? I am very interested in this

Comment: @Mawg sounds good. I didn't indicate I would post a new answer because of [Am I allowed to indicate crosspost links in my questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293152/178179), and I am against paraphrasing or more generally performing unnecessary reformatting.

Comment: Arsclip (clipboard manager) might be able to do this.  Perhaps with macros, I'm not sure.  http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/

Comment: @aparente001 thanks, I wasn't aware of this clipboard manager. It's not obvious to me how when could do auto-complete with it. Does the macro system have access to the word on which the cursor is placed?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Windows On Screen Keyboard might be an option - it shows up with suggestions, but it may not be very accurate/consistent:

[image]